# Add new field in report->sales->orders grid

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new in magento i want to add new field email in magento

---

Reports -> Sales ->Orders inside there is grid i want to add email field 
how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Ranaganathan please clarify and check the question once again because of in the reports we will show the 'counts' am i right then how it is possible ?

Comment: Whether you need login to admin=>Sales=>Orders? please confirm the same thanks

Comment: Please check and confirm http://prntscr.com/f4r2nm  whether you want add like this?

Comment: yes i need to display the email in that grid....first is it possible?@ NAGARAJU K

Comment: whether you have seen my screenshot you need like this only right?

Comment: this page http://www.oscprofessionals.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/magento1-sales-order-report-4.jpg

Comment: yes raghunath i do understand but my question is here we are showing the filtered output reports for example:- number of orders done (count) over the period. hence we can't able to show the customer emails here.

Comment: yanaku purinjidi @Ranganathan better, ungala seniors nandu suggestion edithikonga. (Take suggestions from your seniors) thanks